# exception handling decorator which accepts functions as args

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have an exception handling decorator which looks like this:

```
def error_handler(errors=(Exception, ), default=""):
    def funcator(func):
        def deep_inside(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except errors as e:
                print("i just cought a", repr(e))
                return default
        return deep_inside
    return funcator
```

here's an example usage:

```
date_error_handler = error_handler((ValueError), default="INVALID")

from dateutil import parser

@date_error_handler
def date_parser(date):
    return parser.parse(date)
```

now if i pass something like this:

```
date_parser("12/10/1O")
```

I will get an output like this:

```
#output: 

i just cought a ValueError('Unknown string format:', '12/1O/10')
'INVALID'
```

instead of returning `"INVALID"` I want to pass a function as an argument to `default`(in the `error_handler` decorator) which will take the date string and try to replace if any alphabets were present in it with numbers. for example it would look like this:

```
#alphabet to number replacing function(just for example)
def alpha_to_num(date): return date.replace("O", "0")
```

now i need to pass this `alpha_to_num` as an argument to `error_handler`'s `default` param.

here's an example of expected output and usage:

here's an example usage:

```
from dateutil import parser

@error_handler((ValueError), default=alpha_to_num)
def date_parser(date):
    return parser.parse(date)
```

but now I want to get an output like this:

```
#expected output: 

i just cought a ValueError('Unknown string format:', '12/1O/10')
'12/10/10'
```

how do I do something like this?

Comment: what is the expected output then?

Comment: basically the fixed output. (the last code block above)

Comment: To clarify: you want `default` to **always** be a function? Or do you want to support both "plain values" and function default values? If you always want `default` to be a function just change `return default` with `return default(*args, **kwargs)`. To support both types of values it depends on how you want to handle some hedgecases... I'd personally use two different arguments so that it is clear which case it is when you create the decorator. This also allows to have fixed default values of function type, which would be hard to handle with one argument used for both cases.

Comment: Decorated function's arguments are accessible as a tuple in `*args` parameter. Instead of `return default` just return `args[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the function instead of call to that function. use below code.

edit : added handling if function value is not passed or passed value is not an function.

```
def error_handler(errors=(Exception, ), default=""):
    def funcator(func):
        def deep_inside(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except errors as e:
                print("i just cought a", repr(e))
                return default(*args, **kwargs) if hasattr(default,'__call__') else default
        return deep_inside
    return funcator
```

Comment: what happend if he dont assign anything to default?

Comment: why return None if you have an empty string as default?

Comment: edited answer to handle when the default is not passed or default is not a function.

Comment: This fails for classes: `error_handler(default=list)`. In this case it will return `list` as default value instead of returning a list containing the arguments passed to the function.